# Syntax error SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, sql-update, vba

I am trying to run this SQL query but for some reason it keeps failing saying that there is a missing operator on the line `Imp.FormularyID=F.FormularyID` and I am very confused why.  I have double checked the syntax and everything looks good.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable as Imp
INNER JOIN FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 as F
ON Imp.FormularyID=F.FormularyID
SET Imp.FormularyName=F.FormularyName, Imp.ClientName=F.ClientName
WHERE Imp.FormularyID=F.FormularyID
```

Comment: You don't need that last line. It is already in the join

Comment: What happens if you don't use aliases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal SQL syntax would be;

```
UPDATE Imp 
SET FormularyName=F.FormularyName, ClientName=F.ClientName
FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable as Imp
INNER JOIN FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 as F ON Imp.FormularyID=F.FormularyID
```

Answer (score 0):

(1/2 OT)

Your Sql dialect might not support joins in update statements.

In this case you may resort to correlated subqueries:

```
 UPDATE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable Imp
    SET Imp.FormularyName = (
                               SELECT F1.FormularyName
                                 FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 F1
                                WHERE F1.FormularyID = Imp.FormularyID
                            )
      , Imp.ClientName    = (
                               SELECT F2.ClientName
                                 FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 F2
                                WHERE F2.FormularyID = Imp.FormularyID
                            )
  WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
              FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 F
             WHERE F.FormularyID = Imp.FormularyID
        )
```

This assumes that the `FormularyID` columns are constrained to be unique (ie. PK/AK) in their respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

It worked if I did not use aliases.

```
UPDATE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable 
INNER JOIN FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015
ON ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.FormularyID=FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015.FormularyID
SET ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.FormularyName=FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015.FormularyName, ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.ClientName=FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015.ClientName
WHERE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.FormularyID=FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015.FormularyID
```